# Why is utf-8 not working for me in node.js?

Tags: node.js, utf-8

I am really new in vanilla node.js servers. I know there are easier methods to create your own server (like epxress), but I wanted to create a server from the very basics so I'm not that experienced in this area.

I use two methods: the *.find* and *.filter*. With the *.find* method the text is nice, but with the *.filter* method it looks like the utf-8 charset is just not working.

**It writes it correctly:**

```
res.setHeader("Content-type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
res.write(JSON.stringify(myfile.find((i) => i.id == id), null, 4));
```

```
{
    "id": "A0Eu3M6VXuprBxg",
    "type": "fact",
    "text": "A Minecraft első verziója (akkoriban még Cave Game) hat nap alatt készült el."
}
```

**It writes it wrong:**

```
res.setHeader("Content-type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
res.write(JSON.stringify(myfile.filter((i) => i.type == type), null, 4));
```

```
[
    {
        "id": "A0Eu3M6VXuprBxg",
        "tipus": "teny",
        "szoveg": "A Minecraft elsĹ verziĂłja (akkoriban mĂŠg Cave Game) hat nap alatt kĂŠszĂźlt el."
    },
    {
        "id": "1AKm3NQ8w1329pB",
        "tipus": "teny",
        "szoveg": "A Ghastok hangjai egy alvĂł macskĂĄtĂłl szĂĄrmaznak. NĂŠvszerint a Minecraft hangproducere, Daniel 'C418' Rosenfeld macskĂĄjĂĄtĂłl, aki azt vĂŠletlenĂźl rĂśgzĂ­tette felkelĂŠskor."
    }
]
```

Comment: JSON is not `text/plain`, it is [`application/json` (and a charset definition is redundant)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/477819/4299358).

Comment: You can upvote comments. Or even take the [tour].

Comment: I would like to upvote your comment, but I don't have enough reputation currently. :(